# Rails-Joins VS Retrieval via Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, associations

I am confused as to when/how to use rails' Join methods vs. rails' Associations.

I have a set of objects linked one to the other a train-like fashion: Class `A` `has_many: bs`, and Class `B` `has_many: cs`. I wanted to call a method on all `c`s that are linked to all `B`s that are linked to `A`s. I tried to do this with `a.bs.cs.some_method` and got

```
 undefined method 'some_method' for #<bs::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:…>
```

After searching around, I have come to understand that this means that `a.bs` returns a CollectionProxy object, and you can't call a method--even a method that class `c` has--on a CollectionProxy object of `c` objects.

I tried to find out how it should be done, and bumped in `Joins`. And now I wonder whether a nested join is supposed to be used to do this sort of thing instead? I thought I had seen a long chain of associations being used to do this, but I could be wrong.

So, my question is:

1-What is the correct way to do this?

2-If it can be done with `joins` *and* association-chaining, when should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you want to fetch assosicated objects or method output for collection, use `collect` or `map`.
i.e

```
  a.bs.collect{|b| b.cs.collect(&:method_name)}.flatten.compact
```

Now the above line will give you the results in array format but it is very expensive. Why because it will run queries like this

1) 1st Query to fetch the `a` (this fine)

2) 2nd Query to fetch all the `bs` for `a` using IN query (this is also fine as IN query is just 1 query and it will not take that much time)

3) 3rd: Now for each `b` it will try to fetch `cs` and the number of queries to fetch `cs` will depend on the count of `b`. This is very **expensive**.

## How can we optimize it

We will **eager load**  `cs` for `bs` as well after fetching bs. This way rather than explicity running query for `cs` each time, it will run one query with `IN` which is fine

```
 a.bs.includes(:cs).collect{|b| b.cs.collect(&:method_name)}.flatten.compact
```

Detail:

This will run 1 query to fetch `a`, 1 query to fetch associated `bs` for 
`a` and then one query to fetch associated `cs` for `bs`.

You can read about eager loading concept from this link and it is very helpful concept while fetching large scale data. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

---

To get detail, try this

#fetch some object for a like this `a = A.first`

```
1) a.bs (this will fetch the bs for a in one query 
2) a.bs.includes(:cs) (this will fetch cs as well as bs in two queries .1 query for bs and 1 query for cs) 
3) a.bs.includes(:cs).collect{|b|} (this will display the bs object) 
4) a.bs.includes(:cs).collect{|b| b.cs } (this will display c objects in an array in each b object i.e 2D array something like this #[[c1,c2], [c3,c4], ...]. where [c1, c2] belongs to b1 
5) a.bs.includes(:cs).collect{|b| b.cs.collect(&:method_name)} (this will put the method names in array. you will see arrays in array because of bs has many cs. each single array inside big array represent one b 
6) a.bs.includes(:cs).collect{|b| b.cs.collect(&:method_name)}.flatten.compact (This will make all 2D arrays in single array. read flatten and compact concept.)
```

Comment: Jusy for help to see the difference between eagerloading and join: http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/

Comment: I really like your answer, it's very helpful! 2 Q's, though:

1-I understand the line of code you wrote as: `collect` is being called on the `bs` set of objects, NOT the set of `cs` objects. Nevertheless, the `cs` are made available for the `b.cs` line, thus reducing # of DB calls. Is that right?

2-Is there a way to do this dynamically? Meaning, let's say I don't know at the beginning how many associations I will need to traverse...?

Comment: lets take things 1 by 1. i hope that will be easy.. im using `collect` two times in that line. first time to fetch  `cs` objects  for `bs`. and then second time to fetch the `method name` for all `cs` as well `collect(&:method_name)`. the format is different but both are collect. `includes` keyword is reducing the DB calls. it make several dbs to just one using `IN`. lastly when you say this `I don't know at the beginning how many associations i will need to traverse` i didn't get  what are you meaning.(sorry) can you explain please.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time on me here…much appreciated!
Sticking with the first point for now-when you say that the first `collect` is used to 'fetch `cs` objects for `bs`,' I am understanding that you are referring to the `b.cs.collect…` block that follows the 1st `collect`. Is that right? Or do you refer to the *previous* part `a.bs.includes(:cs)`?

Comment: when im referring to first collect. i mean uptil this part `a.bs.includes(:cs).collect{|b|`. you see `collect{` this is the first collect. let me explain things in step. 1) `a.bs` load `bs` for `a` then `a.bs.includes(:cs)` also load `cs` for the `bs`. load means the sql query is run to fetch them in memory. then comes this `a.bs.includes(:cs).collect{|b|` this will traverse `bs` assosiated to `a` one by one. then this part  `b.cs.collect(&:method_name)` this will fetch the method name from `cs` assosiated to each `b`. but this wont run any query as we have already loaded them in memory.

Comment: if you want i can put this in answer to fetch things step by step to see the difference.

Comment: That would be absolutely awesome--I understand it mostly based off your last comment, but the more ways something is demonstrated the better (especially for others, because comments can get confusing for other readers). So if you can, it would be much appreciated, I am sure!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84952/discussion-between-jo-p-and-athar).